# @Value always gets null in one class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I am newbie in Spring and now I am trying to deal with @Value annotation. I have two classes. One has annotation:

```
public class RssHandler {
    @Value("${theTopic}")
    private String theTopic;
    ...
```

And the other one:

```
public class RestCallImpl implements RestCall {
    @Value("${senderUrl}")
    private String senderUrl;
    ...
```

My properties file is:

```
theTopic=mytopic
senderUrl=http://localhost:8080/
```

My beans xml has all things that I found here in the same issues like propertyConfigurer and beans declaration (as I understand):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed/spring-integration-feed.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>file:/Users/Projects/Java/TestNotifier/resources/application.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- RSS Stuff -->
    <int:channel id="inputRssFeedChannel"/>

    <feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news"
                                  channel="inputRssFeedChannel"
                                  url="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch">
        <int:poller fixed-rate=5000 max-messages-per-poll=100/>
    </feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inputRssFeedChannel"
                           ref="rssPrintOutService"
                           method="printRss"/>

    <bean id="rssPrintOutService" class="TestNotifier.RssHandler"/>
    <bean id="SnsRestCall" class="TestNotifier.RestCallImpl"/>
</beans>
```

When I run my app I perfectly get "theTopic", but "senderUrl" is alway null. Why so? What did I miss? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `RestCall` is your interface and does it managed by Spring?

Comment: why did you give `application.properties` as classpath and file? are both files different?

Comment: @NiteshVirani Yes, it's different files. I am using vars from property file in classpath for debug and external file in production.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try @PropertySource annotation to your class as below

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
public class RestCallImpl implements RestCall {

    @Value("${senderUrl}")
    private String senderUrl;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! No, unfortunately it doesn't work (((

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following :

```
public class RestCallImpl implements RestCall {

  @Value("#{senderUrl}")
    private String senderUrl;
    ...
```

Basically just changing the '$' to '#'.

Comment: Thanks for your help! No it doesn't work neither InteliJ Idea says "Cannot resolve variable" and I get an error when I try to run app.

Comment: Are both variables defined in both of the application properties files ?

Comment: Yes. And I can see the value of senderUrl through InteliJ Idea when it with $... I break my mind why it doesn't work ((( So sad (((